# Kivy installation in Anaconda3 Python 3.5.4 Ubuntu 16.04 Fails

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, anaconda, kivy

First I activated my conda environment using:
`source activate building`

Approaches Tried:

Prerequisites were installed following this https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-example

1. Installing using pip:

   - `pip install cython==0.25.2`
   - `pip install kivy`
   - Result: FAIL

     - Log: https://pastebin.com/m9zu390R
     - **gist**:
       `ld: cannot find -lSDL2
       ld: cannot find -lSDL2_ttf
       ld: cannot find -lSDL2_image
       ld: cannot find -lSDL2_mixer
       ld: cannot find -lSDL2_ttf
       ld: cannot find -lSDL2_image
       ld: cannot find -lSDL2_mixer
       ld: cannot find -lSDL2`
2. Installing using source:

   - `git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git && cd kivy`
   - `git checkout stable`
   - `make`
   - Result: FAIL

     - Log: https://pastebin.com/tjuYWrJ7
     - **gist**: `ld: cannot find -lGL`

I did found kivy packages on Anaconda cloud, but they were for python2.

Comment: Which version of Anaconda are you using, Anaconda2 or Anaconda3? Please share the command line used to create the new environment *building*?

Comment: @ikolim Anaconda3, and the environment isn't created only for kivy, it's an existing environment which has libraries I need, like opencv, tensorflow, numpy, etc. And I want to install kivy in the same environment.

Comment: I presumed that you have installed the *Dependencies with SDL2* inside the virtual environment, *building*.

Comment: @ikolim, the dependencies were installed using `sudo apt` hence in /usr directory, so I created softlinks to those required libsdl.so files in environment's directory which was used as Include directory by the installation.